# Gaussian Elimination - where did I go wrong?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, gaussian-elimination

I have just learned about Gaussian Elimination and I decided to try an example question.

I was trying to solve a question and I realised later that I had copied the question wrong but I still decided to proceed and solve the system of linear equations.

However, when I checked my answer online using an online calculator it gave different values meaning my solution was wrong. I've checked my working out and I can't seem to figure out where I've gone wrong. I'd appreciate if someone could help me figure out my mistake.

I've used an online tool to convert my writing into LATEX but it's kind of messed up. I have no idea how to write in LATEX.  As a result, I have attached images as well:

[Working Out Page 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wAvCX.jpg)

[Working Out Page 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTE02.jpg)

Also, I'd appreciate any suggestions on how to improve my work.

(Next time, I'm just going to pivot on the 3 to avoid fractions.)

Here it is:

Q)
$$
\begin{aligned}
& 3 x-2 y-4 z=3 \\
& 2 x+3 y+3 z=15 \\
& 5 x-3 y+z=14 \\
& {\left[\begin{array}{rrr|r}
3^* & -2 & -4 & 3 \\
2 & 3 & 3 & 15 \\
5 & -3 & 1 & 14
\end{array}\right] \quad R_1 \times \frac{1}{3}=R_1}
\end{aligned}
$$
$$
\begin{aligned}
& {\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & -\frac{2}{3} & -\frac{4}{3} & 1 \\
2 & 3 & 3 & 15 \\
5 & -3 & 1 & 14
\end{array}\right] R_2-2 R_1 \rightarrow R_2} \\
& {\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & -\frac{2}{3} & -4 / 3 & 1 \\
0 & 3 / 3 & 17 / 3 & 13 \\
5 & -3 & 1 & 14
\end{array}\right] R_3-5 R_1 \rightarrow R_3}
\end{aligned}
$$
$$
\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & -2 / 3 & -4 / 3 & 1 \\
0 & 13 / 3 & 17 / 3 & 13 \\
0 & 1 / 3 & 23 / 3 & 9
\end{array}\right] \text { }
$$

\begin{aligned}
& {\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & -2 / 3 & -4 / 3 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 17 / 13 & 3 \\
0 & 1 / 3 & 23 / 3 & 9
\end{array}\right] \quad \begin{array}{l}
R_2 \times 3 / 13 \\
R_3-1 / 3 R_2 \rightarrow R_3
\end{array}} \\
& {\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 0 & -6 / 13 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 17 / 13 & 3 \\
0 & 0 & 94 / 13 & 11
\end{array}\right] \quad R_1+2 / 3 R_2 \rightarrow R_1} \\
& {\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c|}
1 & 0 & -6 / 1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 17 / 13 & 3 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 143 / 94
\end{array}\right] \quad \begin{array}{l}
R_1+\frac{6 R_3}{13} \rightarrow R_1 \\
R_2-\frac{17 R_3}{3} \rightarrow R_2
\end{array}} \\
& {\left[\begin{array} { l l l | l } 
{ 1 } & { 0 } & { 0 } & { 8 0 / 4 7 } \\
{ 0 } & { 1 } & { 0 } & { 9 5 / 9 4 } \\
{ 0 } & { 0 } & { 1 } & { 1 4 3 / 9 4 }
\end{array} \quad \left[x=\frac{165}{47} \quad y=\frac{73}{47} z=\frac{52}{47}\right.\right.} \\
&
\end{aligned}

Comment: I don't understand your question. You got the right answer.

Comment: You can check your work by plugging your answers back into the original equations.

Comment: Impressive for the first post on Math SE. Your answer looks right to me too.

Comment: Your last step should lead to x=80/47 (which is not the correct value). However, you concluded the correct value for all variables correctly....x=165/47, etc....How?

Comment: Hi,

I'm so sorry for not making this clearer in my original post but the answer where x = 165/47 and the other solutions with it are not my solutions - they are the solutions of the online calculator I used to check my working out.

My solutions are in the last matrix where I got x = 80/48 and y = 95/94 and z = 143/94.

Apologies for not making this clearer.

Comment: Hi @NoChance,

Thank you for your response. I understand which step you are referring to but I still believe my row 2 where I have written [0, 13/3, 17/3] is correct. If I am not mistaken, there will be a double negative and instead the arithmetic would be:

[2, 3, 3] +[−2, 4/3, 8/3]=[0, 5/3,17/3]
 
rather than your arithmetic of:

[2, 3, 3] + [-2, -4/3, 8/3]=[0 ,5/3 ,17/3]


 Please let me know if I have made a mistake here as my mind is very fuzzy. (If the comment is hard to read, the difference in our calculations is the 4/3 term as you have made it negative)

Comment: You are correct.

Answer (score 2):

You have done a good work but may be you have missed something near this step (verify again):

$$R1+6\:\frac{R3}{13}\:->\:R1$$
$$R2\:-17\:\frac{R3}{3}\:->\:R2$$

Here is my try, I could not keep using fractions till the end, because of cell 3,3 near the end.

[image]